# I don't understand startActivityForResult

Tags: java, android

I am new to programming and I need to follow a course from school but i came up on a problem which won't let me upload pictures in android studio's and its this

```
startActivityForResult
```

Here is the code

```
imgProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
          Intent photoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoIntent.setType("Image/*");
            //noinspection deprecation
            startActivityForResult(photoIntent, 1);
        }
    });





}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null ){

        imagePath = data.getData();
        getImageInImageView();
    }
}
```

I tried to look on the internet but couldn't find any solutions can anybody help me

Comment: and which part you don't understand? code seems valid, should work, isn't it?

Comment: its like calling async function that will return its result somewhere in the future without blocking the caller.

Comment: `a problem which won't let me upload pictures` ? Where do you have that problem? The only thing i see is that you do nothing with the obtained uri. If you do nothing nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to be aware of:

- This way of intercommunication is deprecated as of API 30.
- Sotrage access infrastructure has changes and specific steps have to be take to gain regular internal storage access privileges. Hence, Unless we use MediaStore, ROOM, or SAF, we'll get `NullPointerException` in most cases; or requested sotrage locations will just create a directory of that name in our com.appd.app's files directory and all interaction will be done from that source.

Anyway, the current method of getting input from called Activity:

###### Imports

```
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
```

###### Liaison object

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityForResultLauncher;
activityForResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>()
{
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result)
    {
        if(result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Intent data = result.getData();

            // handle business...
        }
    }
});
```

- The LAMBDA variation of the above code

  ```
  ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityForResultLauncher;
  activityForResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result->
  {
  if(result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK)
  {
  intentData = result.getData();

  // handle business...
  }
  });
  ```

###### Launch phase

- Then it is only a matter of using that object for handling comms

  ```
  activityForResultLauncher.launch(someIntent);
  ```
- Usually I'd return `RESULT_OK` from *called* Activity when I am done with my work there and invoke `finish()` on it. Then I'm back to the *caller* Activity and we're able to proceed resuming at our overriden `onActivityResult` method section.
- The older methods aren't necessary anymore.

Comment: Please note we still need to include proper permissions in our app manifest to access files. Also, we have to include every Activity to the manifest otherwise app will be crashing on launching any intent for excluded Activities called.